# Leaflet markers do not open popup on click

Tags: markerclusterer, openstreetmap, leaflet, mapbox

I just started using Leaflet and [Marker Clusterer](https://github.com/danzel/Leaflet.markercluster) to organize the markers.

**Problem #1:** When an unclustered marker is clicked, no popup appears.

**Problem #2:** When a cluster is clicked several times, all the markers within that cluster appears, and when one of this marker is clicked, its popup appears! However, after closing the popup by clicking on the map, clicking on any of these clustered markers do not open any popups!

If I only have 3 unclustered markers, the popup works fine. However, as more markers are added, once a cluster forms, clicking on the marker within any cluster will not cause the popup to open!

**Initializing markerclusterer**

```
markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
map.addLayer(markers);
```

**All markers added to markercluster `markers`**

A loop calls on the `render` function to create the `marker` and add it to the markerclusterer's array `markers`. *(ignore the backbone.js code)*

```
ListingMarkerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template( $('#tpl_ListingMarkerView').html() ),

    render: function() {

        // Create marker
        var content = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );
        var marker = new L.marker(
            [this.model.get('lat'), this.model.get('lng')],
            {content: content});
        marker.bindPopup(content);

        // Add to markerclusterer
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }
});
```

**Without markerclusterer**

If I add the `marker` directly to `map` instead of the markerclusterer array `markers`, the popups work fine, so I guess the problem has something to do with markerclusterer.

Did I do something wrong that resulted in such behavior of the popups? All help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what little I know of the cluster marker group, you should do this:

```
var markerGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
markerGroup.on('click', function(ev) {
    // Current marker is ev.layer
    // Do stuff
});
```

To add an event handler to the cluster layer instead, do this:

```
markerGroup.on('clusterclick', function(ev) {
    // Current cluster is ev.layer
    // Child markers for this cluster are a.layer.getAllChildMarkers()
    // Do stuff
});
```

Oh, and read the github [README](https://github.com/danzel/Leaflet.markercluster) carefully, it's all in there...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right versions of everything in your Leaflet + Clusterer stack (Js and Css). Compare against the examples in the Clusterer Github repo.